# Can't generate wicked pdf in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf, wicked-gem

Hi everybody I'm trying to use wicked pdf in rails 4.

I follow this page  https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf.

I did:

```
gem install wicked pdf
```

Then I tried the command

```
rails g wicked_pdf
### And got "Could not find the generator"
```

I'm trying to export a view

Here is the [demo and code](http://runnable.com/U9q8SGlB8ys6OIUf/wicked-pdf-for-ruby-on-rails)

Please somebody can help me to configure wicked_pdf?

Comment: you need add `gem 'wicked_pdf'` and `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'` in your Gemfile, then execute `bundle install` in terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things

First, you need to put this `gem 'wicked_pdf'` and `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Second,
According to the docs instead of

```
rails g wicked pdf
```

You should be entering

```
rails g wicked_pdf
```

Comment: And did you edit your Gemfile?  Because the demo you posted, your Gemfile doesn't have wicked_pdf.  That's the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stunned with same issue recently

`rails generate wicked_pdf
Running via Spring preloader in process 28540
**Could not find generator 'wicked_pdf'**. Maybe you meant 'scaffold', 'helper' or 'mailer'`

OR

```
NameError (uninitialized constant WickedPdf)
```

Resolution is simple. Make sure to reload Spring gem after gem installation.

```
spring stop
```

This moment is barely covered in gem docs since spring is default in Rails 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You surely need To specify some paths! So in your  **config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**
please add (Or Uncomment) this :

```
WickedPdf.config = {
#:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
#:layout => "pdf.html",
:exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

and also in your controller :

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "file_name.pdf",:template => "file Directory/file_name.html.erb"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

and then in terminal

```
bundle
```

And then in terminal

```
rails g wicked_pdf
```

and you add in Gemfile

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

then hit bundle in terminal and all shoud work for rails 5. I bet for rails 4 also